# input elements not coming in one row/line

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am having a drop down and two radio buttons in a div. I am trying to bring these elements in one row but no matter what i do these elements are appearing like stacked on top of another . Please tell me what shall i do to make it come in a single line

[image: Screengrab]

```
<div class="p-6  h-screen w-screen bg-gray-300">
        
         <div class="flex flex-col w-full justify-center items-center">
        <select id="select"><option>Select User </option> </select>
        <input type="radio">None</input> <div><input type="radio">Last reset </input>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements are breaking to a new line because the "flex-col" class sets the flex-direction property to "column". Removing this class will allow all of the elements to display on one line.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="p-6  h-screen w-screen bg-gray-300">

  <div class="flex w-full justify-center items-center">
    <select id="select">
      <option>Select User </option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio">None</input>
    <div><input type="radio">Last reset </input>
    </div>
```

Comment: Now, it is moved to the left side https://imgur.com/a/rdpDT1G

Comment: It looks like your container div (div.p-6) is placed inside of another flex container which is making it a column to the left of the four boxes. Placing this div within its own flex container will ensure that it fills 100% of its row.